# Am I Using SQS Correctly? How To Track Queues Correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a software where a user sends text messages, similar to something like Google Voice. This software also sends automated text messages on certain events. When a user sends a text, a lot of backend operations happen before the lambda responds with a success [takes around 3 to 6 seconds]

We wanted to use SQS since its easy to store messages that break for some reason and for scaling since SQS takes care of managing the lambda's when they succeed or fail.

However, we have an issue. We have two lambdas [one that deals with requests and one that does the text message sending]. The request-dealing lambda responds back with a success if its able to put the message into the queue but we dont know if the SQS lambda was able to do its operation with success. If a user refreshes and the lambda failed, it will look like the user never sent the text message.

I wanted to know what is the best way to deal with this. Im currently trying to experiment with MessageAttributes to track a message but wanted StackOverFlow's opinion.

Comment: Here is what I would recommend. Messages picked up from the queue for processing should have their visibility timeout set to a value that is reasonable for a busy sms sender lambda to handle. Also, I recommend long polling with a timeout. If the SMS send is synchronous, then simply delete the message on success and leave it on fail. You should look into the dead letter queue which is where messages that fail x number of times go, a poison queue. If the SMS portion is synchronous then there is no ideal way to reconcile failed messages in realtime unless your sms provider offers a way to do so.

Comment: MessageAttributes are a good way to add meta data such as MessageType and SuccessFlags or StatusCodes. If your queue is going to process various message types, then you could add a known attribute such as MessageType - for example.

Comment: @RossBush The problem with MessageAttributes is that I want to let the user know that their specific message was successful and SQS does not allow me to filter out by MessageAttributes. For example, I want to filter all SQS messages in a dead-letter queue that has a key of "374iwd73ndw". I can tell SQS to get me all messages with 'key' but not what specific key

Comment: A message queue does not give you this ability. You either have to store the message ID in a storage that can be queried as you need or create a funtion or procees to iterate the dead letter queue.